# call navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia methods, camera cannot focus

Tags: html, camera, focus

I use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia to set up the camera to scan the QR code. When the QR code is small, the camera cannot focus and capture clear images when it is too close. Setting the focusMode does not work.Which big shot can you help take a look? Thank you。 Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>HTML5 QR Code Scanner</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="/assets/js/jsQR.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100vw;height: 1200;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
        <video id="video" width="1200" height="1200" autoplay></video>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="1200" style="display:none;"></canvas>
    </div>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <script>
        var video = document.getElementById("video");
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var result = document.getElementById("result");
        let supportedConstraints = navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints();
        console.log('supported', supportedConstraints)
        const constraints = {
            width: { min: 640, ideal: 1280 },
            height: { min: 480, ideal: 720 },
            advanced: [{ width: 1920, height: 1280 }, { aspectRatio: 1.333 }, { focusMode: "continuous" }]
        }

        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video: {
                    width: 900, height: 900, 
                    facingMode: { exact: 'environment' },
                    advanced: [{ focusMode: "continuous" }],
                    frameRate: { ideal: 10, max: 15 }
                }
            }).then(function (stream) {
                const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
                track.applyConstraints(constraints).then((e) => {

                }).catch((e => { alert('error') }))
                let constraintsData = track.getConstraints();
                console.log('constraintsData', constraintsData)

                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
                setInterval(function () {
                    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 300, 300);
                    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 300);
                    var code = jsQR(imageData.data, imageData.width, imageData.height);
                    if (code) {
                        alert(code.data)
                    } else {
                        result.textContent = "waitting";
                    }

                }, 500);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                result.textContent = "err:" + err;
            });
        } else {
            result.textContent = "sorry";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have currently used several third-party JavaScript plugins, such as html5-qrcode, qr-scanner, vue-qrcode-reader, and have also used native APIs to open the camera. All attempts to focus the camera have resulted in the inability to recognize smaller QR codes on the physical object

Answer (score 0):

I searched for some HTML scanning projects on GitHub and found that none of them can achieve camera focus. When the distance is close, it becomes blurry

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).